# Is libjpeg always installed with Android?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, jpeg

Im writing my entire Android project in NDK C/C++, and I now want to open some jpg files.

Ive read a lot people suggesting compiling libjpeg or libjpeg-turbo for use with NDK, but others suggesting libjpeg is already in with android is this true?

I'd rather use an existing lib but dont want to rely on it if some units its not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
Thanks guys for the help, I was hoping libjpeg was accessible to my development but as pointed out is in Android though not public through the NDK.

So I spent sometime reading the spec for jpg and decided on writing a C decompresser from scratch until I fell upon jpgd by Rich Geldreich, and although C++ its single file implementation of jpeg decompresser in the public domain which Ive now used without any issues on Android.

He also has an accompanying jpge (encodeder) although surplus to my requirements for this project well worth noting.

My NO-JAVA application continues.

Solution:
[C++ jpg Decompressor Android NDK](http://code.google.com/p/jpeg-compressor/)

Answer (score 2):

I use libjpeg-turbo, statically linked with my other libs, it works fine. I don't think libjpeg is already installed on Android.

Comment: Which is fine, just remember *"If you use it in a
   program, you must acknowledge somewhere in your documentation that
   you've used the IJG code."*

Answer (score 1):

Even if libjpeg already exists within android, it's not a public API, so therefore whatever gain you get by not having to bundle it, might come back and bite you later. I'd say it's not worth it - bundling your own copy of libjpeg (or similar) makes sure you don't rely on platform internals.

If applicable, you could use e.g. some of the public java APIs (android.graphics.BitmapFactory etc, which in the end calls the internal bundled libjpeg or whatever) via JNI to decode your images - then you don't have to ship the jpeg library yourself, but have to do a bit more JNI function calls. (There might be a small performance overhead compared to calling libjpeg directly, but not significant unless you're loading huge amounts of images.) If you're interested, I can share example code for this (it's about 50 lines).